# jest custom testEnvironment 'describe' is undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to write a custom Jest testEnvironment. One of the requirement is to be able to replace the globals object with my own implementation/alteration of the globals. Basically, at one point in my code I will be doing this:

```
const JestJSDOMEnvironment = require('jest-environment-jsdom');

class CustomTestEnvironment extends JestJSDOMEnvironment {
    async setup() {
       const sandbox = CreateSandbox(this.global);
       this.global = sandbox;
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Test suite failed to run
    ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

The main problem I'm encountering is that the jest global functions like `describe`, `it` etc are not available anymore in the tests.

I have tried copying all the properties that I have not added through my implementation from the global object and symbols on my sandbox object. The error persists.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the content of `CreateSandbox`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. But it creates an entire Window global based on "this.global". Some properties will be passthrough, some will be wrapped in custom implementations. Not all properties are copied, just a subset.
Note that Object.assign(this.global, sandbox) also ends up showing the same behavior

Comment: The way this works is usually you just create a pre test file that will override your globals. Is that something you could do?

Comment: Yes, I could do that and that is preferred

Comment: Would you like to show an example of how that might be done?